# Is the memory usage of using one dict half the amount that is needed for two dicts?

Tags: python

Let's say I have 2 dictionaries in Python, like this:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
d1[(i, j)] = 10
d2[(i, j)] = 20
```

Instead I could do it like this:

```
d = {}
d[(i, j)] = (10, 20)
```

Accessing it could be done with `d[(i,j)][0]` and `d[(i,j)][1]`.

What I would like to ask is this:

Does the second option need less memory than the first?

If yes, is it half the memory?

I need to use very large dictionaries in a program I am writing and if the second solution is better I would opt for that.

Comment: `Is it half of the memory?` - Yes.

Comment: I suggest doing some [further reading](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) on dictionaries in the python tutorial (subchapter 5.5). Then you can specify better what you want to do. It is quite a different thing if you have two separate dictionaries or only one.

Comment: You should also look at more specialized datastructures like `numpy` arrays, which are optimized for matrix style data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested this on Windows 10 machine in 32bit Python 3.7.3 repl:

This took 155MB of memory:

```
>>> d1 = {(i, j): 10 for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)}
>>> d2 = {(i, j): 20 for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)}
```

And this only 79MB:

```
>>> d = {(i, j): (10, 20) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)}
```

So the second one is obviously better in terms of memory usage, but they are quite different solutions and it's hard to say which one is 'better' overall. It all depends on the use case.

Edit:

The difference is a lot smaller, but still significant when using random values (with unique `id`s).

This took 157MB:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> d1 = {(i, j): randint(0, 100) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)}
>>> d2 = {(i, j): randint(0, 100) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)}
```

And this 119MB:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> d = {(i, j): (randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)) for i in range(1000) for j in range(1000)}
```

Comment: This is surprising. Doesn't a tuple with 2 elements take up more memory than the 2 elements themselves?

Comment: @Barmar I assume so, but the additional dictionary obviously has a lot of overhead.

Comment: Also surprising, I'd expect that to be asymptotically negligible. Maybe the hash table has lots of extra space to avoid collisions.

Comment: Is the second one 1000*1000 tuples, or one tuple and 1000*1000 references to the same tuple?

Comment: @JamesKPolk It is the same `id` in each of them.

Comment: @JamesKPolk `>>> id(d[(2,3)]) 17966064`, `>>> id(d[(999,500)]) 17966064`.

Comment: I don't think OP was assuming that every dictionary entry would be the same.

Comment: No every entry will be different.Does this apply in this case?

Comment: what if you put (i,j) instead of (10,20)?

Comment: ```>>> a = [(10, 20) for i in (0, 1)]
>>> a[0] is a[1]
True```

Comment: @ruohola Thank you!!Just one small thing.If we have 4 elements (i,j,k,l) instead of 2 could you check the memory it needs?

Comment: @pikpapo: You can check the memory usage yourself. If you don't know how, ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @pikpapo Hard to compare since you can't divide 1000000 to 4 loops evenly. You can easily check the memory usages of specific dictionaries with your task manager :)

Comment: So we can assume that the more elements are the same the less memory a dictionary needs?

Comment: @Epitheoritis Yes, obviously. The random examples will need to create a million objects with unique `id`s, so that naturally takes a lot of memory.